# Bean shell script in testng

Tags: testng, beanshell

i want to select multiple methods based on the name of the methods using bean shell script in testNG.xml.This is my current testng.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="methodsuite">
<test name="test1" >
   <method-selectors>
       <method-selector>
            <script language="beanshell">
            <![CDATA[
            String str=System.getProperty("testToRun");
             testngMethod.getMethodName().contains(str);
            ]]>
            </script>
       </method-selector>
         </method-selectors>

  <packages>
       <package name=".*"></package>
   </packages> 
 </test>
 </suite
```

Here i am able to select one method at a time.is it possible to select multiple mmethods using beanshell script?Or can i make use of looping/is looping allowed in the beanshell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can select multiple tests in BeanShell script. Basically TestNG calls your script for each `@Test` method found in your suite (e.g. defined in `<packages>`) and pass additional variables (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell) to it. You can define own functions here etc. Only important condition is - you have to return true/false if you want or not to include 'current' method to test suite. So if you for example change your script to:

```
<script language="beanshell">
    <![CDATA[
        String str = System.getProperty("testPerformance");
        testngMethod.getMethodName().startsWith(str);
    ]]>
</script>
```

All tests which name starts with `testPerformance` will be included in test suite.

Comment: .Thanks jaroslav.here the String "str" has only one value,is it possible to pass the list of string to it(i mean to .startswith)

Comment: No, it's not possible but BeanShell is 'basically' Java (http://www.beanshell.org/) so you can create array and then use for loop.